# Datastage AUtomation

Tags: datastage

I am currently working in a project where we are using CDC Transaction stage which will automatically capture the change data from source.This data is used to create xml which will inturn pass to MQ where MDM will pickup this from MQ.

Now I got a requirement for automating the deployment process in datastage.Currently I am looking for an architecture how to achieve this. So when we did automation of deployment process, there should be some mechanism where I need to stop the CDC transaction process, stop the MQ process and deploy the jobs.Once the deployment is successfull I need to restart the CDC transaction process and MQ process from the point where it stopped. Also I need a rollback mechanis in case if the deployment went wrong. Please let me know all your thought process on this, so that I can create a good solution

Comment: What exactly do you understand under "deployment process"? Are you woried about applying it in the Produnction environment only or about moving it from Dev -> Test-->Prod.

Comment: I need it in all the environments.From Dev--Test--UAT--Prod. I was thinking is there any way we can do this.Is it really achievable